# Какой метод срабатывает при получении пуша, если приложение свернуто или закрыто?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, push-уведомления

*didReceiveRemoteNotification* у меня срабатывает только когда развернуто или если нажать на сам пуш и тем самым развернуть приложение

Answer (score 1):

Срабатывает когда приходит пуш перед показом пользователю:

```
func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void
)
```

Срабатывает когда пользователь взаимодействует(нажимает) с пушем:

```
func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
)
```